# Pad spaces to header row to same as column width Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have converted csv file to psv file, how can I add spaces using Pandas Dataframe to individual header rows to fix the width of each column.(Widths for columns are 16,56,56,42,6,3 respectively)
My table now looks like this I want pad spaces to the header row in the top and also to the row number column on the left side. There need not be any name to the row number column.

```
|Address_line_1|Address_line_2|Suburb|Postcode|State
0|8 Rangeview st          |            |Rochedale    |4123   |qld
1|563 Esplanade           |Retreat     |Urangan      |4655   |qld
.
.
10|8 Byambee               |            |Harlin       |4740   |qld
```

Expected output should be like:

```
     |Address_line_1      |Address_line_2              |Suburb          |Postcode|State
0    |8 Rangeview st      |                            |Rochedale       |4123    |qld
1    |563 Esplanade       |                            |Urangan         |4655    |qld
.
.
10   |8 Byambee           |                            |Harlin          |4740    |qld
```

Comment: You may want to reference this link [Python Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for formatting strings and string literals, especially section 7.1.1.  Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780739/15239951), you can use `to_markdown`:

```
widths = [16, 56, 56, 42, 6, 3]
df.columns = [c.strip().ljust(w) for c, w in zip(df.columns, widths[1:])]
df.index.name = ''.ljust(widths[0])
out = df.astype(str).to_markdown(tablefmt='pipe', colalign=['left']*len(df.columns))
```

Then:

```
out = out.split('\n')
out.pop(1)
out = '\n'.join(l[2:-1] for l in out)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
                   | Address_line_1                                             | Address_line_2                                             | Suburb                                       | Postcode   | State   
0                  | 8 Rangeview st                                             |                                                            | Rochedale                                    | 4123       | qld     
1                  | 563 Esplanade                                              | Retreat                                                    | Urangan                                      | 4655       | qld     
10                 | 8 Byambee                                                  |                                                            | Harlin                                       | 4740       | qld
```

**Update**

You can also use `to_csv`:

```
df1 = df.fillna('').astype(str).rename_axis('').reset_index()

out = (pd.concat({c.strip().ljust(w): df1[c].astype(str).str.strip().str.ljust(w)
                      for c, w in zip(df1.columns, widths)}, axis=1)
         .to_csv(sep='|', index=False))
print(out)  # Or export to a file
```

Output:

```
                |Address_line_1                                          |Address_line_2                                          |Suburb                                    |Postcode|State
0               |8 Rangeview st                                          |                                                        |Rochedale                                 |4123  |qld
1               |563 Esplanade                                           |Retreat                                                 |Urangan                                   |4655  |qld
10              |8 Byambee                                               |                                                        |Harlin                                    |4740  |qld
```

Comment: Hi, I have noticed that I still have 2 issues. 1. There is a space after each pipe character. how can I get the values to be left justified and appear next to pipe. 2. Also the width of the columns should be 16 or 56 etc. inclusive of the value within it how can I make it so with values. Ex: ` 0 |8 Rangeview st | |Rochedale |4123 |qld `

Comment: How 'Postcode' and 'State' can fit in a width of 6 and 3?